# For high message volume, why for the same message am I getting frame_size error in rabbitmq?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a direct type exchange which is routing a message to a queue. I am getting frame size error.

I am using Apache camel `camel_rabbitmq` component for a message publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provide few information, however I would say your problem is related to sending frames bigger frames than accepted. RabbitMQ supports five types of frames, where the BodyFrame is the one that can be splitted in more than one just in case the message is bigger tham max_frame_limit, which by the way defaults to 130K.

Other frame types with size bigger than max limit could be the reason for them to break, maybe something you are adding to the headers of the AMQP message can be a hint.

Hope this can help somehow, anyway if you provide more information that would help.

Comment: header is same for all mesaages. Is there any thing to do with queue limit or something else? I am not facing issue in low volume messages.

Comment: when a queue reaches the limit it drops the package, you can configure a dead-letter exchange to try get those, Also, I have already got some problem with bigger messages that delayed heartbeat frames putting connection down, however I don't remember receiving any frame error, it was a connection closed instead.

Do you mind send the language you are using, and the error message you're getting?